# GoのWAF、Ginのログ出力について

Tags: go, docker

現在DockerにGinとオートリロードしてくれるライブラリ（https://github.com/codegangsta/gin）を入れ、サーバの働きを色々と試しているのですが、Ginで500エラーが発生した場合に、どこにログが吐かれるのかがわからず、デバッグに手間取っております

理想は`fmt.Println`とかで状況を確認できるようにできたり、500番になった場合のエラーがどこかに出力されるようにしたいのですが........

自分で設定するものなのでしょうか？
Goのデバッグの仕方に詳しい方
どうかよろしくお願いいたします

---

こちらがDockerfile

```
FROM golang:latest 

WORKDIR /root

RUN apt-get update \  
&& apt-get -y install apt-utils \  
                        build-essential \  
                        libpq-dev \  
                        vim tmux git curl \
                        locales locales-all \ 
                        --no-install-recommends \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  

RUN go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin \
&& go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint \  
&& go get github.com/codegangsta/gin \
&& go get gopkg.in/mgo.v2 

COPY main.go /root 

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/gin"]  
CMD ["-p", "8080", "run", "main.go"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Dockerのlogs機能を使えばよかったのですね
失礼しました

```sh
docker logs -f <container_name>
```